# How can i replace multiple chars in string in ng repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i replace multiple chars in string in ng repeat in angularjs ?

Here Is My Code and its not working.
i want to replace the #,_,. from the string.How can i replace multiple chars in string.Here Is My Code.

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

<ul>
  <li type="1" ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
    {{ x.replace(/#|_/./g,'') }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {




    $scope.names = [
        "Jana#ai.mkv",
        'Car.l.mkv',
        'Mar##gareth.mkv',
        'Hege.mkv',
        'Jo_e.mkv',
        'G__ustav.mkv',
        'Birgit.mkv',
        'Mary.mkv',
        'Kai.mkv'
    ];
});
</script>



</body>
```

Comment: use a filter to do that

Comment: Or a controller function or map the data before sending to view. Angular can't compile those special characters in the regex in html and such business logic shouldn't be in the view anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function and apply the logic to replace the # inside the function.

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.getText = function(obj){
    return obj.replace(/#|_|\./g, '');
  };
    $scope.names = [
        "Jana#ai.mkv",
        'Car.l.mkv',
        'Mar##gareth.mkv',
        'Hege.mkv',
        'Jo_e.mkv',
        'G__ustav.mkv',
        'Birgit.mkv',
        'Mary.mkv',
        'Kai.mkv'
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
<ul>
  <li type="1" ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
    {{ getText(x)  }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: write your regex inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Correct your regex first. Looks like it should be

```
/#|_|\./g
```

Write a method inside the controller and call it inside the mustach template. For instance

```js
angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.names = [
      "Jana#ai.mkv",
      'Car.l.mkv',
      'Mar##gareth.mkv',
      'Hege.mkv',
      'Jo_e.mkv',
      'G__ustav.mkv',
      'Birgit.mkv',
      'Mary.mkv',
      'Kai.mkv'
    ];

    vm.replace = function(value) {
      return value.replace(/#|_|\./g, '');
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
  <p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
  <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in vm.names | filter: test">
      {{ vm.replace(x) }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```